# The bottom margin of the Rdlc Sub Report does not match the row bottom margin of the parent report

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, reporting, rdlc, subreport

I'm working with asp.net mvc and using rdlc reporthing technology to generate reports. But I'm stuck in a bind.
This is the output of my rdlc report with sub-reports.

[image]

Where My Report Design are

[image]

and

[image]

But I would want a report similar to this one

[image]

in which the sub-report row size grows in lockstep with the parent row size.

Comment: I doubt you will be able to do this as textbox sizes cannot be controlled at runtime with the exception of cangrow/canshrink. You *might* be able to try adding a new column to the subreport, the same size as the `SKU Name` in your parent report, passing the `SKU Name` text as a parameter to the subreport which would make it grow to the same size then hiding that column in the subreport. It's not something I've ever tried and I doubt it will work but might be worth 15 mins of your time to test/

Comment: Your idea was excellent, but it will not work, because  when you set visibility hide, it does not occupy any space on main report

Comment: Sorry it didn't help but at least I know not to try that myself in the future!